# how to access the path where the .coverage file is located after the TFS 2012 Nightly build in build server

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfsbuild, alm

We have enabled Code Coverage for C# projects in the Nightly Build on the TFS 2012 integrated builds.and see the Code coverage completed successfully, However, we are unable to locate the path of the Code Coverage file on the build server? does anyone where can I find it.

Secondly, in the TFS build, is there variable or an attribute to access the codecoverage result path?

Comment: I am waiting to hear from anyone?

Comment: Same question here....